# Buffalo NAS Active Directory Integration Group Policy Changes

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, network-attached-storage, buffalo

as a part of effort to integrate buffalo NAS terrastation pro with our AD, we found out that following changes need to be made in the Group policy;

The following need to be altered in Domain-> Windows Setttings->Security Settings->Local Policies-> Security Options.

Microsoft Network Server: Digitally Sign Communications(always) (Needs to be Disabled, currently its Not Defined)

Network Security: Lan Manager Authentication Level(needs to be altered from Not Defined to Ntlm2 negotiate if needed)

My questions are , is it worthy/risky to change the policy for the domain for couple of NAS servers?

Second one , can they be changed on the individual DC's(probably via SECPOL)  since we will be pointing the NAs to only 1 DC?

Comment: If you have a NAS that's only offering file services to a single client, why wouldn't you just use a DAS?

Comment: @MDMarra: He's not talking about having one client-- he's talking about how the NAS has a "hard coded" DC used for passthru authentication (it doesn't use the DC locator protocol). They're really, really poor devices in terms of their AD integration.

Comment: ...ohhhhh. Yeah, that's ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am familiar with these devices and these particular changes. These settings do compromise security somewhat. I don't know that the practical risk is much better than the [already sorry state of NTLMv2 and hash-based attacks](http://www.networkworld.com/community/blog/owned-60-seconds-zackattack-network-guest-windows-domain-admin), but it does increase risk somewhat. It would be nice if Buffalo spent some money addressing the need to downgrade security to support their devices.

To your second question: Anything you might do to create different security policy for different Domain Controllers (DCs) would result in an unsupported configuration and I'd advise against trying it. It *might* be possible to work something out but you'd be on your own re: support if it created oddball behavior.

Comment: We are further planning to introduce more NAS devices into our environment, do you know of any such devices simmilar to Terastation Pro which have very good AD Integration options?